# php not returning response when hosted

Tags: php, arrays, response, cpanel

My android's server side PHP code is working fine on my local pc's xampp server but it just won't return responses when I upload it to my cPanel

```
<?php
require '../databaseConnector/databaseConnector.php';

$codes=$_POST["codes"];

$statement=mysqli_prepare($con, "SELECT * FROM product_codes WHERE $codes = ?");
mysqli_stmt_bind_param($statement, "s", $codes);
mysqli_stmt_execute($statement);

mysqli_stmt_store_result($statement);
mysqli_stmt_bind_result($statement, $id, $codes);

$response=array();
$response["success"]=false;

while(mysqli_stmt_fetch($statement)){
    $response["success"]=true;
    $response["codes"]=$codes;
}
echo json_encode($response);  ?>
```

Error displayed on cPanel

```
log[Wed Jul 11 06:45:40.608669 2018] [:error] [pid 7330:tid 140534072993536] [client 41.204.187.12:10436] SoftException in Application.cpp:267: File "/home/barnsley/smartscanner/checkvalidity/validity.php" is writeable by group
```

Comment: Which php version you are using?  check your php error log  in the cpanel

Comment: I can not see the php open tag aslo in your code `<?php` , I can see only the close tag

Comment: check your php error log in the cpanel

Comment: I don't believe this is the PHP error log, this is the log of your cpanle complaining about the file permission, but you can try to change your file permission to `644`

Comment: WOW!! Changing the file permission to 0644 from 0666 worked. Thanks so much :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your file permission to `644` so the file can be executed

[Proper permissions for web server's directories and files](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/questions/proper-permissions-for-web-server-s-directory)